# javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.1 HELO/EHLO requires domain address

Tags: jakarta-mail

My web app (java/spring) application in localhost sends email successfully but when i
deploy it on host i got following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.1 HELO/EHLO requires domain address
```

I use java mail library.

web server: tomcat 7

thanks.

Comment: which domain were u using on your localhost and which one is on your production host..? Also, change the domain in your code from localhost to that of your **host** atleast.

Comment: what do you mean from 'domain'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a lot of googling i found the workaround below:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/271097/java/java/JavaMail-Exception-HELO-requires-domain

we should add the following props when creating the session to bypass "send hello first" error:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
props.put("mail.smtp.transport.protocol", "smtp"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "127.0.0.1");
```

but it is a workaround and the root cause is not found.

Comment: The root cause is usually that your machine's name service is not configured correctly.  Perhaps you're using DHCP and there's no host name associated with the IP address you're using?  If the JDK can't get a proper host name for your machine, it doesn't know what to send to your mail server in the HELO command.  The mail.smtp.localhost property overrides that.  (The other properties are unrelated to this error.)

Comment: thanks Bill. my app is running on centos server. as you said the problem was hostname. i modified etc/hosts file and add hostname for 127.0.0.1 ip and the problem is went. thanks again.