# Is SES the only way to send email from Lambda?

Tags: email, smtp, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, amazon-vpc

I am trying to use my company's mailhost for sending email to internal mail groups but I am unable to send an email.
It throws exception as below:

```
"javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.0.0 HELO requires domain address
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1363)"
```

Is it a limitation or I need to use SES only for sending emails?

- Is there any configuration that I need to do and I might have missed?
- Anything to check in VPC if the ports are open?
  Should I use port number as 25 or 587?
- Will it help if I assign the VPC to my lambda?

More details:
1) I am looking to make an email message more readable than what comes from SNS

Thanks!

Comment: did you take a look at this open source repo? https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/

Comment: `but I am unable to do` means nothing if you don't tell what was not working, error message etc., And SES is not the only way to send email. You can use your SMTP servers to send mail.

Comment: What is your use-case? (Feel free to edit your question to add more details.) If you are purely sending notifications internally (rather than pretty emails to customers), the recommended method is to send a notification to an Amazon SNS topic and then people can subscribe to receive emails from that topic.

Comment: Hi all, I updated my question with more details. Kindly let me know if you  need any further clarifications.

Comment: @alexandresaiz: I am not looking for leveraging SES, just simple java mail apis to trigger an email using smtp host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for this from [javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.1 HELO/EHLO requires domain address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841203/javax-mail-messagingexception-501-5-5-1-helo-ehlo-requires-domain-address).

The main property that will fix this issue is           props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", smtpHost);

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks!