# how to throw an alarm from code in a lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Is there a way where I can throw an alert that reaches my mailbox form the code on a lambda function with Node.js without needing to setup SES or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

did you see this answer?
[Is SES the only way to send email from Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165240/is-ses-the-only-way-to-send-email-from-lambda)

He is using a propietary mailhost to send e-mail messages.

Good luck!

Comment: I guess the answer of my question is no. The easiest way is to publish an event using SNS jdk and suscribe your mail to that event.